# Bootcamping Windows 8 Installation issues: Blue screen of death

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, boot-camp

I'm trying to install Windows 8 on my MacBook Pro, using Bootcamp.

I've stepped through the assistant and used the `Create a Windows 7 or later version install disk`, and stored this on a Usb Harddrive.

However, when it decides to restart, I get a nice screen of `Please insert a bootable disk`. Great...

I then tried to reboot my mac while holding down the `Option` key, and verified that my USB Harddrive is infact being recognized as a bootable disk. I then select the Harddrive as my boot choice, and the windows logo appears, with a nice little loader.

However, after a few seconds I get a Blue screen of death, and everything restarts, and back to the `Please insert a bootable disk`.

#### Other things I've tried:

- Used GDisk to change the partition type to GUID.
- Used Disk utility to change the partition to NTFS/FAT32.

I have not tried creating a bootable DVD, as I do not have one available at the moment.

Comment: You are using the current version of Boot Camp I presume?  Previous version of Boot Camp did not support Windows 8.

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of Boot Camp.

Comment: which STOP Code/bugcheck do you get?

Comment: I've got no idea. It gives me the new win8 blue screen, and reboots automatically after a few seconds.